# Handling FreeBSD package upgrades using pkg_add

Tags: freebsd, package-management, dependencies

I'm trying to use FreeBSD's `pkg_add` command to install and upgrade binary packages in a build-once-install-on-multiple-machines sort of scenario.  It works well when installing a new package, but upgrades are baffling me.  For example, if I want to upgrade a package that is **depended on** by another package, I can't just install it:

```
# pkg_add /path/to/somepackage-2.0.tbz
pkg_add: package 'somepackage' or its older version already installed
```

At this point, I can delete the older version of the package if I pass `-f` to the `pkg_delete` command:

```
# pkg_delete -f somepackage-1.0
pkg_delete: package 'somepackage-1.0' is required by these other packages
and may not be deinstalled (but I'll delete it anyway):
anotherpackage-1.0
```

But...and this is the killer...now the dependency information is gone!  I can install the upgrade:

```
# pkg_add /path/to/somepackage-2.0.tbz
```

And now attempts to delete it will succeed without any errors:

```
# pkg_delete somepackage-2.0
```

How do I handle this gracefully (whereby "gracefully" means "in a fashion that preserves dependency information without requiring me to rebuild/reinstall and entire dependency chain").

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've found, `pkg_add` can't upgrade ports gracefully. The `portupgrade` package does this quite nicely however, and is the method I use and recommend (there are others available if you don't like this method).

Once the port is installed you can simply run `portupgrade -aPP` and it will upgrade all ports installed on the system using packages. If you don't want to update ever port, you can run `portupgrade -RPP [category/port]` to upgrade a particular port and the ports it depends on. Running the program without arguments will upgrade the port belonging to the current directory (i.e. `cd /usr/ports/security/openssl ; portupgrade` will upgrade `openssl`, without the `-PP` option it will build the port from source); and if you are not in a port directory it will display help (same as the `-h` option).

**Edit:**
By default portupgrade will install packages if they exist in the directory defined by the `PKG_PATH` environmental variable (defaults to `$PACKAGES/All`, `$PACKAGES` defaults to `$PORTSDIR/packages`; so the default path is `/usr/ports/packages/All`).

If they don't exist there, it will download the packages (by preference) from `$PKG_SITES` (takes a URI with subfolders `Latest` and `All`; no default value), or `$PACKAGEROOT` (takes a URI with the normal mirror path under it; default is `"ftp://ftp.freebsd.org"`).

One easy way to do this, use one machine to build/cache packages that will be installed on other machine.

- You can build packages from the ports tree with `make package` in the port's directory (which will also install the port).
- You can use `portupgrade` to upgrade one machine and cache the package files for use on other machines, the aforementioned commands will cache the package files in the default directory (see above).
- You can use portupgrade to fetch the packages only, and not install them, with `portupgrade -aPPF` or `portupgrade -RPPF [category/port]`.

Once you have the cached package files you can share the directory via NFS, FTP, HTTP, etc; so long as the files are accessible from the other machines. Set the `PACKAGES` or `PKG_SITE` with the appropriate values to point to the caching server. Execute the typical `portupgrade` command, it should pull the packages from the caching server and install them.

Note: The port tree has to be up to date on all the servers for `portupgrade` to operate correctly (it will attempt to update to whatever version is in the local ports tree). If you're going to have the same ports/packages installed on all the computers, it might be easiest to share one servers `/usr/ports` directory (say over NFS) and mount it on all the other servers.

Comment: What I want to is to (a) use locally built packages, if available, or (b) use packages from a remote repository.  What I'm trying to avoid is the situation where I need to upgrade a package when the port is more recent than the available binary package on the mirrors...building it on the target system will pull in all the build dependencies, which isn't desirable.  Building it a dedicated build host would work great if it's possible to tell portmaster to look into multiple locations for binary packages.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `pkg_replace` is what you are looking for.

I'm using it for quit a some time now. One of my FreeBSD machines acts as build server and builds ( using `portmaster` ) all packages for the other machines. I'am using `pkg_replace` to install these prebuild packages on all other machines.

http://www.FreeBSD.org/cgi/url.cgi?ports/ports-mgmt/pkg_replace/pkg-descr

Answer (score 0):

Or you could rely on Portsnap or CVSup, described here:

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports-using.html

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question.  Portsnap and CVSup take care of keeping the ports tree up-to-date, but have very little to do with updating installed packages.  Tools like portmaster and portupgrade bridge both worlds, but have their own issues.